# Can't call external API from Swagger UI inside Gitlab. Error with Content Security Policy

Tags: gitlab, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I’m trying to use an OpenAPI file into GitLab (which runs the UI for my file) but when I use the feature Try Out/Execute from Swagger UI (which sends a request to an external API) I get an error with Content Security Privacy.

My OpenAPI works on Swagger Editor online, and in Gitlab don’t. I think that I need to set this external URL but I have no idea where to do it. Maybe something in my OpenAPI code? Or a setting in GitLab?

The error:

[image]

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: This s a known issue, reported here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19515#note_350046862

Answer (score 0):

Just change a file name to:

> openapi.yaml